# Unable to expand or show the data on clicking of icon using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

From the following code, I can able to search my data and can able to expand/collapse the respective data on clicking of icons: `+/-` to `show/hide`  the data on `filtering` or `searching`.

html:

```
<div ng-controller="repeatPeople">
<br>
<p>
<input type="text" id="search" ng-model="searchPeople" 
 placeholder="Search" >
</p><br><br>
      <table border="0">
        <thead style="background-color: lightgray;">
          <tr>
           <td style="width: 30px;">Click</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Gender</td>
          </tr>  
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat-start="person in result = (people | filter:searchPeople)"> 
                    <td ng-init="person.expanded = !person.expanded">
              <button ng-if="(result.length > 0 && searchPeople) && person.expanded" ng-click="setExpanded(person)">-</button>
              <button ng-if="!(result.length > 0 && searchPeople) || !person.expanded" ng-click="person.expanded = !person.expanded">+</button>
                   </td>
            <td>{{person.name}}</td>
            <td>{{person.gender}}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr ng-if="result.length > 0 && searchPeople && person.expanded" ng-repeat-end="">
            <td colspan="3">{{person.details}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

js:

```
function repeatPeople($scope) {
  $scope.people = [
    {name: "John", gender: "Male", details: "Hi ! I am John and age is 25. I do dance well.",expanded:false},
    {name: "Mary", gender: "Female", details: "Hi ! I am Mary and age is 30. I read books.",expanded:false},
    {name: "Dan", gender: "Male", details: "Hi ! I am Dan and age is 20. I like to play cricket.",expanded:false},
    {name: "Alex", gender: "Male", details: "Hi ! I am Alex and age is 35. I like to watch movies.",expanded:false},
    {name: "Rosy", gender: "Female", details: "Hi ! I am Rosy and age is 25. I play Guitar.",expanded:false}
  ];
 $scope.setExpanded = function(person){
   person.expanded = !person.expanded;
 }

}
```

But, I am unable to expand the data on clicking of icon: "`+`" by default if I execute this code. I can able to `expand/collapse` the data on filtering or searching. Please let me know how to fix it to work show/hide and search properly. Thanks in advance.

Created [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/zmoejqdm/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `ng-if="result.length > 0 && searchPeople && person.expanded"`. Initially this condition will be `false` because `searchPeople`is not set.

I've [updated your fiddle as well as made some simplifications](https://jsfiddle.net/184zfh7o/1/).

Also try avoiding [`ngInit`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) to initialize the properties of your items in the array since it adds unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates.

**UPDATE:** Based on your comment, you want to expand the user section on search, so then I think it is better to use [ngChange](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) event on the input and filter + process the repeated data in your controller. [See updated fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/184zfh7o/3/)

Comment: thanks for your reply, it is fine, now one more issue is there: the data is not expanding on filtering or searching. We need to click on "+" icons to expand now manually. I need it should be expanded on filtering as well. Please let me know and Thanks in advance !

Comment: @Guna Please take a look at my updated answer, hope it helps you.

Comment: It's fine. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using `ng-if="(result.length > 0 && searchPeople) && person.expanded"` as `$scope.searchPeople` is `undefined`.

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var app = angular.module('uigrid', []);

  app.controller('repeatPeople', ['$scope', '$templateCache', function ($scope, $templateCache) {
   $scope.people = [
   {name: "John", gender: "Male", details: "Hi ! I am John and age is 25. I do dance well.",expanded:false},
   {name: "Mary", gender: "Female", details: "Hi ! I am Mary and age is 30. I read books.",expanded:false},
   {name: "Dan", gender: "Male", details: "Hi ! I am Dan and age is 20. I like to play cricket.",expanded:false},
   {name: "Alex", gender: "Male", details: "Hi ! I am Alex and age is 35. I like to watch movies.",expanded:false},
   {name: "Rosy", gender: "Female", details: "Hi ! I am Rosy and age is 25. I play Guitar.",expanded:false}
   ];
   $scope.setExpanded = function(person){
    person.expanded = !person.expanded;
   }
   $scope.setExpanded2 = function(person){
    person.expanded = !person.expanded;
   }

  }]);
 </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="uigrid">
 <div ng-controller="repeatPeople">
  <br>
  <p>
   <input type="text" id="search" ng-model="searchPeople" 
   placeholder="Search" >
  </p><br><br>
  <table border="0">
   <thead style="background-color: lightgray;">
    <tr>
     <td style="width: 30px;">Click</td>
     <td>Name</td>
     <td>Gender</td>
    </tr>  
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="person in result = (people | filter:searchPeople)"> 
     <td ng-init="person.expanded = !person.expanded">
      <button ng-show="(result.length > 0) && person.expanded" ng-click="setExpanded(person)">-</button>
      <button ng-show="!(result.length > 0) || !person.expanded"  ng-click="setExpanded2(person)">+</button>
     </td>
     <td>{{person.name}}</td>
     <td>{{person.gender}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-if="result.length > 0 && searchPeople && person.expanded" ng-repeat-end="">
     <td colspan="3">{{person.details}}</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, as per above solution, if I click on the icons: "-", the data is not expanding or I cannot see any data on expanding(clicking of "-" icon, but I can see on filtering or searching with expanding). Please let me know how to do this and thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Check [this updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/PrashantShirke/184zfh7o/4/).

Further more to the changes suggested by @Stanislav, you can expand the row on filter may be using `$watch`on `searchPeople` (`forEach` may impact on performance though if list is huge)

```
$scope.$watch('searchPeople', function(val) { 
   angular.forEach($scope.people, function(person) {
     person.expanded = !!val;
   });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try to remove `searchpeople` and it should work. Also remove `ng-init` from the `td` to make it collapsed by default.

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var app = angular.module('uigrid', []);

  app.controller('repeatPeople', ['$scope', '$templateCache', function ($scope, $templateCache) {
   $scope.people = [
   {name: "John", gender: "Male", details: "Hi ! I am John and age is 25. I do dance well.",expanded:false},
   {name: "Mary", gender: "Female", details: "Hi ! I am Mary and age is 30. I read books.",expanded:false},
   {name: "Dan", gender: "Male", details: "Hi ! I am Dan and age is 20. I like to play cricket.",expanded:false},
   {name: "Alex", gender: "Male", details: "Hi ! I am Alex and age is 35. I like to watch movies.",expanded:false},
   {name: "Rosy", gender: "Female", details: "Hi ! I am Rosy and age is 25. I play Guitar.",expanded:false}
   ];
   $scope.setExpanded = function(person){
    person.expanded = !person.expanded;
   }
   $scope.setExpanded2 = function(person){
    person.expanded = !person.expanded;
   }

  }]);
 </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="uigrid">
 <div ng-controller="repeatPeople">
  <br>
  <p>
   <input type="text" id="search" ng-model="searchPeople" 
   placeholder="Search" >
  </p><br><br>
  <table border="0">
   <thead style="background-color: lightgray;">
    <tr>
     <td style="width: 30px;">Click</td>
     <td>Name</td>
     <td>Gender</td>
    </tr>  
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="person in result = (people | filter:searchPeople)"> 
     <td >
      <button ng-show="(result.length > 0) && person.expanded" ng-click="setExpanded(person)">-</button>
      <button ng-show="!(result.length > 0) || !person.expanded"  ng-click="setExpanded2(person)">+</button>
     </td>
     <td>{{person.name}}</td>
     <td>{{person.gender}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-if="result.length > 0 && person.expanded" ng-repeat-end="">
     <td colspan="3">{{person.details}}</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```